# Color the area below the line in a highchart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts

I need to modify a line chart (that I didn't create). The app extracts data from a database and order each element by hour before adding it to the chart. When you hover a point, the app look like this:

[image: hover chart]

My task is to paint the below area with a different color (like an area chart):

[image: chart comparison]

This is the code that generates the chart:

```
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('production-time-chart', {
    legend: {
        /*Not relevant (i think)*/
    },
    time: {
        timezoneOffset: new Date(Date.now()).getTimezoneOffset(),
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttonSpacing: 10,
        buttonTheme: {
            width: 120
        },
        inputDateFormat: '%H:%M:%S',
        buttons: /*Not relevant (i think)*/,
        selected: currentNavigatorButton,
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        plotBorderWidth: 2,
        events: {
            click: () => clearPoints(),
            selection: function (e) {
                clearPoints();
                if (e.xAxis.length > 0 && e.yAxis.length > 0) {
                    var models = [];
                    var chartObj = this,
                        xMin = e.xAxis[0].min,
                        xMax = e.xAxis[0].max,
                        yMin = e.yAxis[0].min,
                        yMax = e.yAxis[0].max;

                    if (chartObj.series[0]) {
                        chartObj.series[0].data.forEach((elem) => {
                            if (elem.x >= xMin && elem.x <= xMax && elem.y >= yMin && elem.y <= yMax)
                                if (elem.options.selectable) {                                    
                                    //selectPoint(elem);
                                    models.push(elem.options);
                                }                            
                        });
                    }                    
                    evalPointsChart(models);
                }
                return false;
            },
            redraw: function () {                
                var [min, max] = calculateNavigator();                
                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, false);                
            }
        },
        height: 500
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Minutos'
        },
        crosshair: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null//'Hora'
        },        
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            //day: '%e. %b'
        },
        events: /*Not relevant (i think)*/
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            point: {
                events: /*Not relevant (i think)*/
            },
            marker: /*Not relevant (i think)*/,
            allowPointSelect: true,            
        },
    },
    navigator: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            showInNavigator: true
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {            
            return ['<b>' + toTimeStr(new Date(this.x)) + '</b>'].concat(
                this.points ?
                    this.points.map(function (point) {
                        return `<b> ${point.point.options.partnumber ? point.point.options.partnumber + " - " : ""}
                                    ${point.series.name} 
                                </b>: ${point.y} mins.`;
                    }) :
                    []
            );
        },
        split: true
    },
});
```

And this is the code used to add a serie:

```
chart.addSeries({
        color: '#2F86A6',
        lineWidth: 3,
        name: name,
        keys: ['x', 'y', 'name', 'selectable', 'partnumber', 'rawObject', 'marker.lineColor', 'marker.lineWidth'],
        data: data,
        showInNavigator: true,
    });
```

I look for solutions here but they either use two separate series to display 2 different charts or have a very different way to create the chart. The closer that I came to resolve the issue was adding the property "type: 'areaspline'" to the chart constructor, but it overwrites the style and hide the points:

[image: area chart]

My goal is to add color to the area below the points, but preserving the style and functionality. Tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Have you had a look at highcharts documentation and tried implementing a [pattern-fill](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills) for this? [This is what you're after yes?](https://jsfiddle.net/7aydekp0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `areaspline`, you need to use `area` series type and change `plotOptions.line` to `plotOptions.area` or `plotOptions.series`. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      ...,
      marker: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  }
```

---

```
chart.addSeries({
    type: 'area',
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ufrb273t/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/chart-types